# Codeigniter multiupload function

Tags: codeigniter, multi-upload

I'm tring this for 2 hours but I can't do it. 
I have a form where is 3 inputs (multi file). 
I have upload_id1, upload_id2 and upload_id3 
when I upload on id1 it upload on on id1, id2 and id3 too.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['galphoto']['name']); $i++) :

    $data = $this->upload->get_multi_upload_data($galp);

    if (!empty($data)) 
    {
        $many_image = $data[$i]['file_name']; 
        $dataphoto = array
        (
            'photo' => $many_image,
            'tours_id' => $id,
        ); 
        $this->db->insert('gallery_tours', $dataphoto);
    }
endfor;

$galp2 = 'galphoto2';
$this->upload->do_multi_upload($galp2);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['galphoto2']['name']); $i++) :

    $data = $this->upload->get_multi_upload_data($galp2);

    if (!empty($data)) 
    {
        $many_image = $data[$i]['file_name']; 
        $dataphoto = array
        (
            'photo' => $many_image,
            'tours_id' => $id,
        ); 
        $this->db->insert('gallery_hotels', $dataphoto);
    }
endfor;

$galp3 = 'galphoto3';
$this->upload->do_multi_upload($galp3);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['galphoto3']['name']); $i++) :

$data = $this->upload->get_multi_upload_data($galp3);

    if (!empty($data)) 
    {
        $many_image = $data[$i]['file_name']; 
        $dataphoto = array(
            'photo' => $many_image,
            'tours_id' => $id,
        );
        $this->db->insert('gallery_hostels', $dataphoto);
    }
endfor;
```

Comment: show the html code of your form pls

Answer (score 0):

Try to set ENVIRONMENT to development in index.php under your root directory to display your errors. Make sure your images save path is writable.

As far as I know, do_multi_upload is not built-in method in upload library of codeigniter.

But if you use this [library](https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload) please read proper documentation for that, its already given and also mention this in your question and update your code.